# My application runs fine, but when I toggle to full screen the screen maximizes but the design stays the same size

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tabcontrol, maximize

Visual Studios 2015, C# Language, Windows Forms.
Using Dev Components and Metro framework

Okay, so I'm just about done my application and it runs very well.
As I run my program testing and published, it doesn't seem to be perfect.
When I hit the maximize button the window expands to full screen just as should. But my internal design stays the same size. My whole screen is a "Tab Control". I don't have menu strip.
Is there a way I could have it grow to full window, OR even... Have the tab control jump to center of the screen during maximized?

I'm just trying to come up with a simple solution to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to search but didn't find answers.
I'm hoping to find a simple solution.

Comment: Is the control docked?  ie. Set Dock to Fill

Comment: Thank you for the replay, excuse me for the newbie questions. Where would I find the Dock command/selection? I see there is a dock setting in the events tab but its blank.

Comment: Select your control, and in the properties tab it is in the Layout section.  [Docking Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-and-anchor?view=netdesktop-7.0)